# socket.io-redis getting trailing bytes error in redis 3.0.6

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io-redis

I'm using `phpredis` to send data to `node.js` via `pubsub` method. After upgrading node.js to the stable version 4.2, I'm getting `trailing byte` error from `socket.io-redis` module.

node.js

```
var pub = redis.createClient(2222, '127.0.0.1',{no_ready_check: true})

pub.auth(redisPassword);

var allsub = redis.createClient(2222, '127.0.0.1',{return_buffers: true,no_ready_check: true})

allsub.auth(redisPassword);

allsub.subscribe('somekey');

io.adapter(RedisStore({pubClient:pub,subClient:allsub}));
```

The error:

```
   Error: 256 trailing bytes
        at Object.decode (/usr/apps/js/node_modules/msgpack-js/msgpack.js:200:47)
        at Redis.onmessage (/usr/apps/js/node_modules/socket.io-redis/index.js:93:24)
        at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
        at RedisClient.emit (events.js:172:7)
        at RedisClient.return_reply (/usr/apps/js/node_modules/redis/index.js:697:22)
        at ReplyParser.<anonymous> (/usr/apps/js/node_modules/redis/index.js:324:14)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
        at ReplyParser.emit (events.js:169:7)
        at ReplyParser.send_reply (/usr/apps/js/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:302:10)
        at ReplyParser.execute (/usr/apps/js/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:213:22)
        at RedisClient.on_data (/usr/apps/js/node_modules/redis/index.js:550:27)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/apps/js/node_modules/redis/index.js:105:14)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

In order to find out the problem ,I have downgraded `socket.io` to 1.36, but the error still persists.

I have followed the solutions suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis/issues/17), but they don't work.

1.Adding return_buffers: true to the instances doesn't work.

It would cause this warning when restart:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node node.js`
listening on *:3000
[TypeError: input.split is not a function]
```

2.Changing the dependencies to msgpack-js-v5 suggested in the last post but that isn't working, like this:

socket.io-redis/index.js

```
var msgpack = require('msgpack-js-v5');
```

socket.io-redis/package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
 "async": "0.9.0",
 "debug": "2.2.0",
 "msgpack-js-v5": "*",
 "redis": "2.4.2",
 "socket.io-adapter": "github:automattic/socket.io-adapter#de5cba",
 "uid2": "0.0.3"
 },
```

It's just so out of nowhere. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: same error and no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Hope you redis is:

`var redis = require('redis');`

and RedisStore is:

`var RedisStore= require(socket.io-redis);`

also add the host port to your RedisStore in io.adapter like:

`io.adapter(RedisStore({ pubClient: pub, subClient: allsub, host: '127.0.0.1', port: 222 }));`

It works for me... Let me know if you have problems..